On hover the div inside button reduces height to give animation and little dark bottom. But text also moving up how to fix not move text
I want to create a button as shown in the code. Where on hover the div inside button reduces height to give animation and dark bottom. But the text also moves up how to fix not move text.
Please suggest what I am doing correctly to achieve this button animation.


.effect-btn {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: #d9d94c;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.effect {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  //   top: 100%;
  top: 0;
  //   left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #f2f255;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.effect:hover {
  height: 90%;
}
<button class="effect-btn">
          <div class="effect">Text</div>
        </button>



